# How to get a dot instead of colon in table captions?

Tags: tables, captions

Now I have

> Table 1: Title

I need

> Table 1. Title

Comment: What about renewing the `\thetable` macro?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

```
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
```